# sed : delete all lines NOT containing string A or B, starting at 2nd line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Please help - I'm stuck.

I need to

1. delete all lines of a textfile
2. which does NOT contain foo or Foo
3. starting from the 2nd line of the file

**infile**:

```
first line 
foobar 
tree 
fish
Foo Bar
Football
Foobar
Street
foo bar
```

**outfile**:

```
first line
foobar
Foo Bar
Football
Foobar
foo bar
```

I tried the following:

`sed '2,$/*.foo.*\|.*Foo.*/!d' -i test.txt`

The resulting error is:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `/'

What's my mistake?
(awk would be a possible alternative, too.)

Comment: What does your `2nd` means? Can you clarify it

Comment: Sample file with expected output should be mandatory.

Comment: Why is football not part of the output?

Comment: Sorry, did copy the wrong content. Is now corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -e '2,${/[fF]oo/!d}' file
```

---

> **-e** *script* (*--expression=script*)
>
> Add the commands in *script* to the set of commands to be run while
>   processing the input.

`2,$` - an address range, considers the lines from the second line to the end

`[fF]` - character class, matches either `f` or `F`

`/!d` - deletes lines which don't contain `foo` or `Foo`

Comment: I also misunderstood the question, OP wants to delete lines NOT containing foo or Foo

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio, yes, there was some confusing moment

Comment: Maybe `sed '1!{/[fF]oo/!d}' file`?

Comment: @potong, for simple case - yes. An address range will be more flexible in case of "dynamic" ranges

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR==1 || !/foo|Foo/' oldfile > newfile
```

Note: If you use csh or tcsh, you need to protect the `!` with backslash:

```
awk 'NR==1 || \!/foo|Foo/' oldfile > newfile
```

Comment: detail `awk 'NR==1 || !/[fF]oo/' oldfile > newfile`

Answer (score 2):

A chance but without `sed` neither `awk` (don't know if they are mandatory  in your case), you can copy the first line of your textfile in a new file:

```
head -1 textfile > newfile
```

Then you can append all the content with foo or Foo to the new file:

```
grep "foo\|Foo" textfile >> newfile
```

So you will have the desired content in newfile.

If you want to have it in your original file then you can move it:

```
mv newfile textfile
```

If first line contains foo or Foo it will be printed twice, but as you stated you wanted to keep the first line, I assume that it won't have neither foo nor Foo.

Comment: actually, the first line will be twice in the newfile

Answer (score 2):

In awk. First some test data:

```
$ cat file
1 begin
2 asd
3 foo
4 sdf
5 Foo
6 end
```

The code. `print` records after the first record that contain `foo` or `Foo`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || /[fF]oo/' file
1 begin
3 foo
5 Foo
```

Comment: OP ask all BUT first :-)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I noticed, complained in comments, got depressed and gave up. Not my day. Fixed.

Comment: @James Brown Sorry for not describing the in/output properly at first! Now added some data within question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A good option is to invert your requirements - delete all lines, but print first line and all lines with foo or Foo.

`sed -n '1p; /foo\|Foo/p'`

This one will print the first line twice if it contains foo or Foo, but that can be easily fixed if needed.

Answer (score 2):

another awk in the forest

```
awk '!a++||!/[fF]oo/' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:

```
sed '2,$/*.foo.*\|.*Foo.*/!d'
```

The issue here is that you are using two forms of line-addressing, namely the numeric (`addr1,addr2`) and matching (`/REGEX/`). In addition, there are errors in your regular expression.

Here is how I would solve it:

```
sed '1b; /[fF]oo/!d' infile
```

Output:

```
first line
foobar 
Foo Bar
Football
Foobar
foo bar
```

Comment: POSIX version (non GNU sed): `sed -e '1b' -e '/[Ff]oo/!d' infile`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Thor!
Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[fF]/&&!/fish/' file

first line
foobar
Foo Bar
Football
Foobar
foo bar
```